# codeigniter no muestra la img

Tags: codeigniter-3

Tengo un metodo que inserta muy bien en la ruta que especifique en el ordenador...pero al momento de sacar la img a html me sale

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto la llamda al html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido @Verito Nogales a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: También es recomendable que el código esté en texto para facilitar su revisión